# Bind window icon to Image

Tags: wpf, image, window

Alright so what I have is a custom Window control. What I'm trying to do is set an `Image` control and I'm trying to set the `.Source` to the `Window.Icon` property.

What I have is

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (OctgnChrome));
private Image IconImage { get; set; }
```

and in the constructor

```
IconImage.SetBinding(IconProperty, new Binding("Icon") {UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged});
```

OctgnChrome is the name of the custom window.

The problem is that the window has an icon, and it shows up on the taskbar when I run, but the `Image` doesn't show anything, it's just blank.

Any ideas on how I can fix this, or what I may be doing wrong?

## Also

If I set it to point directly at an icon specifically, it works, like this

```
IconImage = new Image{Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Octgn;component/Resources/Icon.ico")) };
```

Comment: Please refrain from putting unnecessary clutter in the title. Platform/technology information is already conveyed via the tags, and i'll hazard a guess that most people who want to answer questions browse by tags anyway, so they know exactly what the questions they currently see are about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems I can see.

1. The property isn't actually tied to the dependency property (it uses its own getter/setter).
2. The property isn't named to match the binding+DP registration you've set up, ie, it should be named `Icon` instead of `IconImage`.
3. The type of the property is different than what you're binding to (`Image` vs `ImageSource`).

I suggest implementing the `IconImage` property like this instead:

```
public ImageSource Icon 
{ 
    get { return this.GetValue(IconProperty) as ImageSource; }
    set { this.SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
}
```